# Web service without using a framework

Tags: web-services

I have created a simple web service using Apache Axis, but I understand very less. So I want to create a simple web service without using any framework. Is it possible, if yes, please give some info/links.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a web service without you need to write your WSDL by hand (That's the definition of the web service which the framework creates for you).

Once you create the definition you need to publish it, and you need a server to do that(I'm jumping some steps cause is not than easy as it sounds). It's very uncommon to write webservices without a Framework.

Instead of axis you could use JAX-WS (http://jax-ws.java.net/). Is easier than axis.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I did it. And I don't need to create the WSDL by hand. The wsgen and wsimport tools generate all the stubs (WSDL, XSD, etc.) for us.